# How to export the milling layer properly with Eagle 8.0?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, gerber

I've got one of those jack power plugs with the thin rectangular pins on one of my PCBs.

[image]

The milling layer in Eagle shows the "slits" to be drilled as expected (in cyan).

[image]

I export the `.drd` and `.mil` files with `excellon.cam` and `gerb274x-mill-drill.cam` respectively (job files). However when I upload my gerbers to Eurocircuits, the "PCB Visualiser" thing does not display the slits but only the dot holes.

[image]

How can I make sure Eurocircuits got the right information? Using a gerber viewer on my computer I *do* see the slits from the `.mil` file.

Comment: On EuroCircuits you have to add a milling option and select the outlines that are to be milled.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks for the tip, it saved me quite some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On EuroCircuits, you have to do the following:

1 - Change the milling length you desire (left menu on the PCB Viewer):

[image]

[image]

2 - Access the "Milling Editor" to select the desired outlines to be milled (right menu on the PCB Viewer).

[image]

Here you select the layer on which the outlines are, and then click on the outlines. Its quite straightforward but a bit of a lengthy task on PCBs with lots of milled parts. Maybe there is an auto option but I never tried it.

I was going to add a screenshot but the webpage crashed. I'll edit it in later.